Why might the getImage function not send a request to the backend and instead return cached data?
I have a getImage function that connects to my backend to fetch today's Astronomical Image of the Day and its details. Since I'm using the Next.js App Router (which defaults to server-side rendering unless specified), I expected the function to fetch the data using SSR. However, the issue is that the function is not hitting the backend but instead seems to be using cached data.
For additional context:
The Information component is a client component.
Below are snippets of my Home page and the getImage function.
import getImage from "../../lib/nasa/astronomicalPic";
import Information from "../../components/home/astronomicalPic";

export default async function Home() {
  async function getData(){
    try{
      const data=await getImage();
      
      return data;
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      return null;
    }
  }
    const data = await getData();
    if (!data) {
    return (
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
        <p className="text-xl font-bold text-red-600">Failed to load data.</p>
      </div>
    );
      
    }
return (
  <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
    <Information data={data} />
  </main>
);
    

}


const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL;

export default async function getImage() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${url}/nasaImage`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Error loading image: ${res.statusText}`);
    }

    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    throw new Error("Error loading Astronomical Picture of the Day");
  }
}

I attempted to fetch data from my backend using an async function (getImage) in the Home component. Since the Next.js App Router defaults to server-side rendering unless specified otherwise, I expected the data to be fetched on the server and passed to the component for rendering.
I structured my code to handle the fetched data and conditionally render either the Information component (if data was available) or an error message (if the data was missing). However, instead of hitting the backend to fetch fresh data, it seems to be using cached data, which I wasn’t expecting.
I also tried adding error handling and logging in the getImage function to debug the issue, but I didn’t see any network requests to the backend in the logs or browser's network tab.

What exactly makes you think that your client is using cached response content? Have you checked the "Network" developer tool in your browser? That will show you what is actually happening, and you won't have to guess.
